# Flexbox in css grid: how to position the flex items

Tags: css, html, flexbox, css-grid

I am new to using flexbox to position items within a css grid layout.  The grid layout is three large cells 10%, 35% and 55% of viewport.  In the second grid cell (marked "b"), I use flexbox to position a header and a subheader.

My problem is that I am not able to accurately position the header and subheader within the grid cell "b".  Also, the header is takes up too much space in the vertical direction, thereby pushing the subheader too low.

Here is the html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Welcome to Project</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body class="site">

<div class="grid">
<div class="a">
<div class="a_left">

<div>Logo for Project</div>

<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="b">

<div class="b_left">
    <h1>This is the main header, it's longer than the subheader</h1>
</div>

<div class="b2_left">
<h3>This is the subheader</h3>
</div>

</div>

<div class="c">
<h2>This is grid-template-row c</h2>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the css code:

```
@charset "utf-8";

body{
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.grid {
display: grid;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
grid-template-rows: 10% 35% 55%;
}

.grid > * {
background-color: darkgray;
color: white;
padding: 2em;
}

.a{
    display: grid;
    background-color: lightgray;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: green;
    font-size: 16pt;
}

.a_left{
    display: flex;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: left;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.a_right{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: right;
    vertical-align: right;
}

.b{
    display: grid;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 16pt;
}

.b_left{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    flex-grow: 0;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: left;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: left;
    height: 0px;
    max-height: 0px;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.b2_left{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    flex-grow: 0;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: left;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: left; /*space-between*/
    height: 0px;
    max-height: 0px;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.c{
    display: grid;
    background-color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16pt;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

site-nav{
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.topnav {
    align-content: right;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 100%
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

h1{
    color:  blue;  /*deepskyblue;*/
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    font-size: 28pt;
    text-indent: 30px;
    height: 0vh; /*0px*/
    width: auto;
}

h2{
    color:  lightgray;  /*deepskyblue;*/
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-indent: 12px;
}

h3{
    color:  gray;
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    font-size: 18pt;
    text-indent: 85px;
}

a:link { color: green; }
a:visited { color: blue; }
a:hover { color:red; }

.site{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: grid;
}
```

My questions are:  (1) how can I precisely position the starting point of each of the header (within b_left) and subheader  (within b2_left), and (2) how do I set the max height for the flex container that holds each of the two.

I have done a lot of research on this, and I have mixed and matched properties, but flexbox and grid both have a lot of properties and I still haven't found the right combo.

Thanks very much for any help.

EDIT:  one possibility is to use position: absolute for each, and on the subheader set top: 150px, but I hope there is any way to do this without absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

**(1) how can I precisely position the starting point of each of the header (within b_left) and subheader (within b2_left:**

The starting point is given with the properties of justify-content (start, between, end).

Second, I dont get it correctly, do you want to position the header above the subheader with flexbox? 
If yes, maybe you want to set `flex-direction: column;` because this put all elements inside one above another.

[In this link you can find more information about justify-content an its posible values](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp)

**how do I set the max height for the flex container that holds each of the two.**
I'm not sure if flexbox admit max height configuration, because its height is calculated depending on container's size.

*Hope this can help you.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, flex-direction: column doesn't make any difference and none of the justify-content settings makes a difference.  So far only absolute positioning does it, but that's not my preference.